# My monitor doesn't auto-turn off!

Tags: windows-vista, display, nircmd, power-options

I have Windows Vista and I've set up my display to turn off after 1 minute of inactivity in Power Options. However, it simply doesn't.

I also tried a utility called "nircmd" which has a "power monitor off" command. It indeed turns the monitor off, but it wakes up again one or two seconds later. So my guess is that something is making Windows thinks the computer is active when in fact it's not.

What could be causing this?

**EDIT:** like most computer users, my system does have some processes that are not native running. These are the ones I can spot without digging too deep:

- NOD32
- Evernote
- Dropbox
- Google Desktop
- Affixa
- Everything (a fast search program for NTFS)

Comment: Do you have any programs/non-system-critical processes running?

Comment: Yep, see edit above!

Comment: Do you have some sort of optical mouse?  I have seen these jitter in the past and cause similar problems.

Comment: @steve: yes, I have a Microsoft Optical Mouse! i'll try disconnecting it and see what happens!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem went away after formatting and reinstalling, thus the problem must have lied in some erroneous application present in my previous system.

Answer (score 1):

Do u have any graphic card on your computer, if yes check in device manager under display adapters if drivers are installed or not. If drivers are successfully installed open command prompt and type command "powercfg -h".