# Power off screen not working in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, display, power-management

I've searched here and found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/165847/monitor-doesnt-sleep-on-power-off) for windows 7. Would this be applicable to Windows 8 on a laptop? I would be surprised if we have to fiddle in the BIOs to get a basic function working...?

I'm helping someone with a new Samsung series 5 laptop with windows 8 installed. we have set the screensaver and the battery/AC power options. The screensaver turns on after the set amount of time, but the laptop screen does not turn off after 5 or 10 minutes (depending on battery/AC). We've updated the machine and restarted several times, etc.

We are quite disappointed that a brand new Samsung with Windows 8 can't even turn off the monitor correctly.

Suggestions?

Comment: So, did Windows update fix it? If so, please feel free to remove your edit and answer your own question

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have resolved itself after restarting the laptop once more, at which time we noticed that Windows continued to install further updates. After this, the screen turned off after the specified period of time.

Comment: This is in fact not resolved. Windows 8 still appears to randomly ignore the power setting and leaves the monitor on the laptop on with the screensaver running.